# Redrawing Google Pie Chart with AJAX

Tags: ajax

I am using the following pie chart code that is being fed data from a query:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Customers', 'Status'],
          ['Accepted',     <?php echo $rowsaccepted ;?>],
          ['Declined',      <?php echo $rowsdeclined;?>],
          ['Not Reviewed',  <?php echo $rowsnreview;?>]
        ]);

        var options = {
                       'width':200,
                       'height':200,
                       'backgroundColor':'#474747',
                       'legend': 'none',
                       'chartArea':{left:20,top:0,width:250,height:250},
                       colors: ['#ef8200', '#007fc2', '#41cf0f'],
                       fontSize:14,

                   };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

and the following AJAX call that updates my DB upon clicking a button; therefore updating the chart data, but I must refresh the page for the chart to refresh:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(".decline").click(function(){

var element = $(this);
var del_id = element.attr("id1");
var order_id = element.attr("data-order1");
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "decline.php",
   data: {id1:del_id,order_id1:order_id},
   success: function(){cache: false}
});
  $(this).parents(".show").animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow")
  .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");

});
});
</script>
```

Is there any way I can add a call in my AJAX function that will refresh and redraw the pie chart without requiring the page to be refreshed?

Thanks!

Comment: do the pie chart script inside a function and you just need to call that function in whatever event you want